# what is a vanilla schema?

Tags: database, schema, db2, product

Can anyone tell me what a Vanilla Schema is?

Somebody asked me the "vanilla" database schema of my product. I don't understand the term vanilla here.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Basic schema - no bells and whistles. i.e. a Product table may have ProductID and ProductName but no further specific fields.

Comment: yep - the 'stripped down basics' - 'main ideas'... from a reference to 'plain vanilla'

Comment: @Barry Kaye & Randy Why don't you write this like an answer, and not only as a comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Vanilla Schema would, in general teams, be a schema that comes out of the box as part of something(depending on your context this could be a product to any other source from where you are sourcing the schema). It simply means an "untouched" schema or "plain" or "basic" schema without any modifications what so ever.